# The best way to do this?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I have following design (I am using Auto Layout):

```
——————————————————————————————
|           Button           |
——————————————————————————————
|         V.Tableview(1)     |    --------> Vertical Tableview
——————————————————————————————
|         H.Tableview        |    --------> Horizontal Tableview
——————————————————————————————
|         V.Tableview(2)     |    --------> Vertical Tableview
——————————————————————————————
```

Upon clicking the button, it will show the `V.Tableview(1)`, and the `H.TableView` alongs with `V.Tableview(2)` will be pushed down and `V.Tableview(2)` will shrink according to left screen space.

After a selection on `V.Tableview(1)` is done, `V.Tableview(2)` will collapse and H.Tableview alongs with `V.Tableview(2)` will go up and `V.Tableview(2)` will expand again according to left screen space.

What is the best way to do this in iOS? In Android I can do this very easy but I don't have any idea how to do this in iOS.

Comment: What the "V" and "H" means?

Comment: lol sorry, just edited